# C# Linq to XML getting the elements where value of name contains a specific string

Tags: c#, linq

I have an XML file that contains following type of elements:

```
<add name="$(ReferAEP)" value="$(addressA)" />
<add name="$(ReferBEP)" value="$(addressB)" />
```

what is the linq to xml query to get only elements where "name" attribute contains a value like *EP ? so the above two elements will end up in the result?

Comment: Are the tag names always "add"?

Comment: @jdweng : yes, but there are other elements where name="xyz" where xyz does not contain EP

Comment: I usually use a dictionary : Dictionary<string,string> dict = doc.Descendants("add").GroupBy(x => (string)x.Attribure("name"), y => (string)y.Attribute("value")).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have an outer element for the xml tags specified in your question like:

```
<adds>
    <add name="$(ReferAEP)" value="$(addressA)" />
    <add name="$(ReferBEP)" value="$(addressB)" />
</adds>
```

Then use the below linq query:

```
var query = from d in xdoc.Descendants("adds").Descendants()
            where d.Attribute("name")?.Value.Contains("EP")
            select d;
```

Comment: Beat me to it. Although I would use `EndsWith()` rather than `Contains()`.

Answer (score 4):

Are you looking for something like

```
document.Descendants("add").Where(element => element.Attribute("name").Value.EndsWith("EP)"));
```

Comment: Just wondering if this is going to work as `name` ends with `EP)`

Comment: @Sid Thanks, fixed.

Comment: Well done ;) Actually i prefer yours over `Habeeb` answer even if both works. +1